# TextBox TextChanged event does not fire when Visible = False?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox, textchanged

I have a textbox bound to a datasource. The textbox's TextChanged event updates another textbox.

The problem is, I do not want the first textbox to show, so I set its Visible property to false.

However, now the `TextChanged` event does not fire!

I can work around it by setting `Visible=True`, `Left=-100000` on form load, but I'd like a proper solution.

Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: What kind of TextBox: WinForms, HTML or WPF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your `textbox.Visible = false` in the FormLoad event instead of in the designer. It has to do with handle creation. If the textbox is not visible during construction, then the handle is not created. If the textbox is made invisible after construction, then the handle will have been created and events will occur.

See this [**discussion**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/a5b53eda-7fc2-46e4-b9f5-f64d2885bbff) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to the accepted answer is to set up the TextChanged listener on Loaded, this works for me just the same (in Silverlight at least) and keeps the designer view as it should be.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me where my control was inside a pop-up (so wouldn't display until open), and so using the accepted answer had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

What type of datasource is it? It might have an event that you can use directly instead of using a textbox to listen for an update.

Answer (score -1):

If `Visible` is equal to false then the `Control` is not rendered. Therefore it will be unable to fire an event.

Instead, set the `style` to `display:none`. You can set/unset this programmatically using the `Attributes` collection:

```
MyTextBox.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I was talking about winforms. Added the tag to the question.